# Use php array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach

I have an array like:

```
foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
   $array = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
}
```

I need to use that array in a javascript later in the page but outside of the foreach.
Is that possible? I have tried using json encode:

```
foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
       $array = json_encode(wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ));
    }
```

And then in the script:

```
<script>
var json = <?php echo json_encode(); ?>
</script>
```

But it does not work probably, i guess it's because it's outside the foreach?

//Simon

Comment: var json = <?php echo json_encode(); ?>

Thats just an empty json! :) Pass an variable to json_encode!! :D

Comment: You're not passing anything in to `json_encode()`... See http://uk1.php.net/json_encode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build the array in the loop, then encode and echo it

```
$array = array();

foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
     array_push($array, wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ));
}

<script>
var json = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know why i did not think about using array_push- Thank you very much, it works perfectly! :)